# conditional progressive or simple

Tags: conditional-constructions, politeness

I know this one is not a new one but as I have not received  any answer

Shall I say

If I was a detective, I would ask or I would be asking

Is the second one (be asking) only a form to stress politeness

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but "***I would ask***" sounds much more natural. "*I would be asking*" simply sounds awkward (since *asking* is generally a very quick action and is not done progressively). The progressive might be acceptable if you plan to ask questions for a long time:

> I would be asking all of the neighbors a lot of questions

This roughly means:

> I would spend my time asking all the neighbors a lot of questions

If you want to stress politeness, you could add uncertainty by saying "*I **might** ask*".

---

Note that this is a counter-factual conditional (i.e., you are not actually a detective), so the subjunctive *were* is appropriate:

> If I were a detective...

As written, "*If I was a detective...*" means "*If, at some point in the past, I was a detective...*" which you might ask if you had lost your memory and could not remember if you ever worked as a detective:

> I don't remember clearly, but I think I might have been a detective before I got amnesia. If I was a detective, then someone at the police office might recognize me.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the difference as pertaining to politeness or a manner of speaking. To me, it is more like the following:

1. If I were a detective, I would ask that all fellow detectives be cautious in approaching the target.
2. This case is very fascinating.  If I were a detective and knew the trade, I would be asking you lots of questions right now.